# Unable to install discord.py with pip

Tags: python, pip, discord

I have Python 3.8 and every time I try to install discord.py with

```
py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py
```

it says:

```
> File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite#egg=discord.py[voic
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Can't do only `pip install discord`?

Comment: use pip3 install discord

Answer (score 2):

Use `pip install discord`. If you have multiple versions of Python installed on your machine, (like MacOS) use the python version then the command. For example (On MacOS versions and Linux), with `python3.8`, use `python3 pip install discord`. For Windows you would do `py -3 pip install discord.py` if you wanted to specify to use the version of `python3.8` on your system.

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
pip install discord.py[voice]
```

In your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just go to the Pypi site, [download the wheel](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/19/69/85b43ab22d9deb62340b1ae1f94228453a212bf9bb44fc0a0a9120241d91/discord.py-1.4.1-py3-none-any.whl) and in the directory where your file now lies :

```
py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py-1.4.1-py3-none-any.whl
```

Answer (score 1):

I use Python 3.8 and I had that error as well. The way to do this is to just open up command prompt and type in
`pip install discord`